# Building out a custom upload box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: ignore the dropdown menu]

I am trying to build out a similar input above. I am having a hard time finding the resources to customize a file upload. What I want to achieve is once a file is selected the Icon shows above the file with the option to delete it before it uploads.

Anyone have a resource I can look over or perhaps know a way to achieve this?

Comment: A good practice will be if you try to do it. Don't get me wrong, we love helping people. But it is really important to test your curiosity and finding a way of solving problems. And when ever you are stock, your questions will surely be answered. See the [How to, Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: For sure. I’ll get back to this question when i run into problems with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Customizing a file upload button is a common annoyance. For some reason, it's rendered by the browser & OS. Essentially, you have to hide it and replace it with your button.

Wrap the button in a div in your HTML:

```
<div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
  <button class="btn">Upload a file</button>
  <input type="file" name="myfile" />
</div>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.upload-btn-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  color: gray;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file] {
  font-size: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

The original button is enlarged to 500px (just a large number so it takes up the entire div), and has its overflow hidden by the div. That way, the entire div will trigger the file upload event. Opacity is set to 0 to visually hide it, yet still render the element.